# Vertical ScrollView inside Swiper Kivy python

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm trying to create kivy MDSwiper with vertical ScrollView in it. Here is my code.

```
<MySwiperItem@MDSwiperItem>
    do_scroll: True
    width_mult: 1

    ScrollView:
        MDBoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            adaptive_height: True

<MySwiper@MDSwiper>
    items_spacing: 0
    do_scroll: True
    MySwiperItem:
    MySwiperItem:
    MySwiperItem:
```

And it nicely scrolls vertically only. And the horizontal scroll from mdswiper disappeared.

I have also tried to create GridLayout instead of BoxLayout and even change the source of kivy swiper class, but the effect is still awful. Help please